# Deleted everything but members from a SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I created a SharePoint sub-site, and accidently deleted all permissions groups except for the Members (which included me) and now I'm stuck looking at the site I've created but I'm not able to edit or delete it and create a new one.

Any idea of what I could do to get myself out of this situation?

Thanks,
Ash

Comment: Are you a site collection admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use an account that's in the Site Collection Administrators.

If you're not able to view the Site Collection Administrators (in Site Settings), you'll need to contact the admins of the site and ask them to re-assign you Full Control permissions to your site so you can begin rebuilding your site permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you can still sign-in with the system account.

If not try adding the system account to the Site Collection Administrators. (In the settings of the root site of the site collection. )